# Using ng-options with different objects in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array `things` with different objects in it, for example 2 differenz objects:

```
{name: 'book',
value: '5', 
color: 'blue'}
```

and

```
{name:'pen', 
length: '10'}
```

Now I want to show all these things in a droplist using `ng-options`.
So I can do:

`ng-options="(thing.name + ', ' + thing.value + ', ' +  thing.color)" for thing in things"`

If the current Object is a `book`, it will be fine but if it's a `pen`, I get a mess.
Is there a possibility to differentiate between the objects that I want to show in the droplist or a better practice for that?

Comment: So you want to show all options from both objects in the single dropdown?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could do some if'ing and else'ing in the template to get the data fields to come out the same, such as

`ng-options="(thing.name + ', ' + (thing.value ? (thing.value + ", " + thing.color) : (thing.length))" for thing in things"`

...but that's ugly as sin and will be difficult to maintain, especially if you have more than those two irregular object types in your `things` array. You're probably better off massaging the data ahead of time in the directive link function to generate a clean array containing the options strings you want embedded.

For example if all you're looking for is a comma-separated list of the fields in each "thing":

```
scope.myCleanOptions = things.map(function(thing) {
    return Object.keys(thing).join(", "); // or whatever
});
```

Comment: Thanks, something like your ugly method is what I've been searching for. In my case, it's okay, because the extent is not getting much more complex. Can you explain to me more exact what you're doing in your second option?  Whats that `map` and `keys` ?

Comment: Both are part of vanilla js:  `Array.map()` is a convenient way to generate array X based on the contents of array Y.  (You could use angular's `$filter` service to do more or less the same thing if you prefer, or just write a plain old `for..in` loop and construct the returned array manually.)   `Object.keys(foo)` just returns an array of all the field names inside foo (which I then joined into a comma-separated string using `.join(', ')`.)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to `copy` and `extend` your objects, into a new one.

So something like:

`var mergedObj = angular.copy(bookThing); // clone bookThing into mergedObj
angular.extend(mergedObj, penThing); // extend mergedObj with the contents of penThing`

And now use mergedObj for your dropdown list. You may need to use the `track` by in your `ng-options` to state which property is your key.

So something like:

`ng-options="item.name for item in mergedObj track by item.name"`